# NodeJS Regex match 4 digit number in string with 'OR' words

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to regex string with a year inside. Template is 'Year-<4 digits>-"high OR low"-level'.

I've built this regex: /Year-\d{4}-\b(low|high)\b-level/gi;
In online regex testers my strings pass the check. Sample code:

```
const template = /Year-\d{4}-\b(low|high)\b-level/gi;

const txtArr = ['Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-high-level', 'Year-low-level', 'Year-high-level', 'Year-2018-low-level', 'Year-2018-low-level']

for (const s of txtArr) {
    console.log(template.test(s), s);
}
```

I expect 2 of sample strings to not pass, but 4 should pass. But they dont - only 2 of them pass. Also in browser console they don't pass. Tried in FF and Chrome. Can't understand why.
Also, if I copy the string that is not passing the match and just make

```
console.log(template.test('Year-2018-low-level'), 'Year-2018-low-level');
```

it passes! I've got only one idea: looks like in every iteration of loop something is not reset in regex, and it keeps something in memory, that is not letting match pass.

P.S. I even copied the same string which must pass the test to array, like that:

```
const txtArr = ['Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-low-level']
```

and the results are true-false-true-false-true... Why? And how to fix?

Comment: That's indeed very suprizing, especially considering that changing `template.test(s)` to `/Year-\d{4}-\b(low|high)\b-level/gi.test(s)` fix the problem...

Comment: It also works when you remove the `global` statement.

Comment: All the explanation [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an explanation here: https://siderite.dev/blog/careful-when-reusing-javascript-regexp.html

> "The moral of the story is to be careful of constructs like _reg.test(input);
>   when _reg is a global regular expression. It will attempt to match from the index of the last match in any previous string."

So the problem comes from the way the `global` statement is treated.

The author of the blog also describes the very same problem you have:

> "Here is a case that was totally weird. Imagine a javascript function that returns an array of strings based on a regular expression match inside a for loop. In FireFox it would return half the number of items that it should have."

What you could do to avoid this problem is either not using the `global` keyword, or instanciate a new regex at each iteration:

```
const txtArr = ['Year-2019-low-level', 'Year-2019-high-level', 'Year-low-level', 'Year-high-level', 'Year-2018-low-level', 'Year-2018-low-level']

for (const s of txtArr) {
    console.log(/Year-\d{4}-\b(low|high)\b-level/gi.test(s), s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `!!s.match(template)` instead of `template.test(s)`, so you don't need to modify your regex.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-carson-z9cq6

An explanation to the weird behavior:

> The RegExp object keeps track of the lastIndex where a match occurred,
>   so on subsequent matches it will start from the last used index,
>   instead of 0.

from this StackOverflow question: [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your regex and its working, with this one:

`const template = /Year-\d{4}-(low|high)-level/`

[image]

Comment: Also, seems that "g" flag is making regex fail.